# Correct way to return REST Api response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am developing a REST API for a website, let's say i have a POST endpoint('/users/create') which i want to create the user if they don't already exist and return the user as a result.
What this would look like is:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/users/create")
public User createUser(@RequestBody UserDTO form)
```

The problem with this is that when the user is successfully  created there is no problem just returning the user with a response code 200. The problem comes when I am doing input validation and for example a user with that email already exists and i want to return user: null and some sort of message as to what specifically failed in the user creation. I've thought about multiple posibilities such as creating a custom object that has fields for both an object of any type ( user in this case ) and a message along with it, as well as using HttpServletResponse / ResponseEntity. They all seem like they are overcomplicating something that should be realtively simple in my eyes and i don't know which approach is the best. First time posting so excuse me if i'm a bit all over the place.

Comment: you can probably have a Standard Response Object whose "data" field can be user or any object that you wish to return. It can additionally have a "success" key denoting the success of the response. This is all in addition to the http error codes(4XX - client error, 5XX - server error)

Answer (score 0):

there probaly is an solution which uses the Http error system but as an alternative I would use an if statement on both sides, which checks if the user already exists and if it does it sends user:error or something like that. The client side then has to check if the anwser is a user or error and if it is error a pre programmed message is shown